# Could not connect to ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ using django channels

Tags: django, websocket, channel

I was trying to make a websocket connection using django channels. gs1 is my project name and app is an app inside the project

When I run python manage.py runserver and type ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/sc/ in postman and press connect I am getting "Could not connect to ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/sc/" error in postman and "Not Found: /ws/sc/" error in the backend.

These are the modifications I made in my settings.py file :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'channels',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app',
]

ASGI_APPLICATION = 'gs1.asgi.application'
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'gs1.wsgi.application'
```

This is my asgi.py file :

```
import os

from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
import app.routing

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'gs1.settings')

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'http': get_asgi_application(),
    'websocket': URLRouter(
        app.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
    ),
})
```

This is my routing.py file :

```
from django.urls import re_path
from . import consumers


websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path('ws/sc/', consumers.MySyncConsumer.as_asgi()),
    re_path('ws/ac/', consumers.MyAsyncConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

This is my consumers.py file :

```
from channels.consumer import SyncConsumer, AsyncConsumer


class MySyncConsumer(SyncConsumer):
    
    def websocket_connect(self, event):
        print("Websocket connected....")

    def websocket_receive(self, event):
        print("Message Received....")

    def websocket_disconnect(self, event):
        print("Websocket disconnected....")


class MyAsyncConsumer(AsyncConsumer):
    
    async def websocket_connect(self, event):
        print("Websocket connected....")

    async def websocket_receive(self, event):
        print("Message Received....")

    async def websocket_disconnect(self, event):
        print("Websocket disconnected....")
```